# How to projection element in multi array field of MongoDb collection?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, projection

Is there a way to get only specific field values ​​from a multi array?

```
db.test.insert({'id':'stack', 'nums':[{'name':'Dave', 'num': 1, 'phones' :[{'id':1, 'number':'000-000'}, {'id':2, 'number':'000-001'}]}]})
```

```
{
    "_id" : "63b3896a5b5d9de96b6277fa",
    "id" : "stack",
    "nums" : [
        {
            "name" : "Dave",
            "num" : 1,
            "phones" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "number" : 0
                },
                {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "number" : -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**the answer i want**

> {'id':1, 'number':'000-000'}

I want to print only the value with 'id' 1 in 'phones'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$nums"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "phones": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$nums.phones",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.id",1]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BWaJ50_J_U9)